# Bash - Problems creating array from a command output which has quoted text with spaces

Tags: bash, array, command-substitution

For an script I'm making I need to convert the output of a command to an array. 
For simplifying I have made an example using echo:

```
arr=( $(echo '"test example" "test2 example"') )
```

What I want is the first element of the array to be

```
test example
```

but when doing this:

```
echo ${arr[0]}
```

I get

```
"test
```

What I have to do to get the result I want?

Comment: You don't need the `echo` there. What you can do is `arr=("test example" "test2 example"); echo "${arr[0]}"`.  This is how you create an simple array in bash.

Comment: @val0x00ff _"For an script I'm making I need to convert the output of a command to an array.For simplifying I have made an example using echo"_ 

The example here is made with echo because people can test it. The real script executes another program. So I can't simply remove echo.

Comment: What does the output of the actual command look like? The format you show here, with quotes, is not the best way to do it: it's hard to parse in a way that makes sense (the `eval` method suggested in an answer is dangerous since the output of the command will be evaluated — whatever controls the output of that command can cause your script to run whatever program they want) and the definition is ambiguous (e.g. can you have a `"` in an element? how? What do you do if the output doesn't contain balanced quotes? …).

Comment: The output is :
`"word word" "word word"` (...)
It outputs two words with a space in the middle of them surrounded by quotes and each one of these separated by spaces. If there are quotes they are escaped `\"`.

The eval as you and @ilkkachu said has risks. 

I might look into either changing the program I execute if I can or making my own replacement so the output can be more easily used, maybe using mapfile.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose **echo** do not produce right output like a command so have to include **sed**

```
mapfile -t arr < <(
    echo '"test example1" "test2 example2"' |
    sed 's/" "/"\n"/g'
)
```

Comment: I like this approach better, using mapfile, but it doesn't seem to work. The array appears empty. :S

Comment: @MarcMarquezSantamaria You are right. All time forgot subprocesses. Settled.

Answer (score 1):

```
eval "arr=( $(echo '"test example" "test2 example"') )"

echo "${arr[0]}"

for e in "${arr[@]}"; do
   echo "<$e>"
done
```

## output

```
test example

<test example>
<test2 example>
```

Comment: @MarcMarquezSantamaria, `eval` is the easy way here, but just note that it runs the whole input as a shell command, doing much more than interpreting the quotes. Variables in the quoted strings will be expanded, so if the output contains `$` it may get corrupted. Also, anything _outside_ quotes will be taken as shell syntax, e.g. an unquoted `)` will break the array assignment syntax. Also, if someone actively wants to ruin your day, command expansions will be an easy way to do that.